# img not displaying properly after closing bootstrap modal

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-transitions, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to build a gallery where every image has a hover effect ([this one](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CaptionHoverEffects/index3.html)). When I jhover the image and click the link inside , a bootstrap modal opens showing some content.

Until here works fine, however, when I close this modal, the image is not displaying properly in the main page. You can see my problem here:

http://www.bootply.com/90dGFlCrxI

Can anyone explain me what am I doing wrong?
Thanks very much guys!

Comment: the issue is the overflow: hidden; you need to right a workaround in your css for this issue.

Comment: did you try the answer I suggested, but you deleted that question and re-posted this new one with same issue?

Comment: Ups, yes sorry Shehary. I deleted because I had written the code in bootply. I swear i didn't realized there was another answer. I have already undeleted and I proceed to try your answer.

Comment: I would suggest not to un-delete the question and proceed with the @AlvaroJoao answer, it;s almost same suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems be the

> overflow: hidden;

in this css rule:

```
          .effect figure {
               margin: 0;
               position: relative;
               /*overflow: hidden;*/
               text-align: left;
           }
```

if you remove the issue is fixed.

another work around:

```
    .effect figcaption {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        left: 0;
        padding: 7px;
        background: #26BC8A;
        color: #ed4e6e;
        height: 50px;
        top: auto;
        bottom: 0;
        opacity: 0;
       /* transform: translateY(100%); */
       /* transition: transform 0.4s, opacity 0.1s 0.3s; */
}
```

the translateY is not working as expected.

Comment: Yes it doesn't happen anymore, but my transition is not the same too. If I remove this one the figure does not do the effect I need.

Comment: I can tell you that. it's right answer, samething i suggested the OP but he deleted the question and re-posted again

Comment: Yeah sorry for that. Do you @Sehary want me to delete the other again? I'm sorry, I'm new here and still don't know how to act correct.

Comment: About that, it's ok, But why is not working? If I can't solve this there is no point on the translateY effect for the image. Should I change the entire effect? Thanks guys

Comment: have you tried?, this transform wont impact the overall feature of the page. You can try another transform, as  the linear.

Comment: Yes I tried. I will play around and make the effect work this way. Thanks Alvaro