# Disappearing content after close bootstrap modal

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-transitions, bootstrap-modal

I had [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32741456/img-not-displaying-properly-after-closing-bootstrap-modal?noredirect=1#comment53328683_32741456) issue using another effect in my gallery. Since I couldn't figure out how to mantain using that effect, I changed to another hover effect in my images, but still is not working.

[Bootply exemple](http://www.bootply.com/Jyn985hnsg)

When I close the modal which was open clicking the link, the image I clicked, disappears.
Is any way I can close the modal without my images disappearing?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Please not use the poposed solution by Shehary because if you debug it you can see a js error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add  top:0px to figcaption styles

```
figcaption {
-ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
filter: alpha(opacity=0);
opacity: 0;
position: absolute;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background: rgba(38, 188, 138, 0.8);
color: #fff;
text-align: center;
-webkit-transition: all .8s ease;
-moz-transition: all .8s ease;
-o-transition: all .8s ease;
-ms-transition: all .8s ease;
transition: all .8s ease;
top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: That works perfect, thank you very much @SebriZouhaier! Your dedication is very much appreciated.